# How do I log out of Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, logout

How do I log out of Stack Overflow?

Comment: You don't -- it's infinite recursion. We've trapped you here FOREVER!

Comment: logout on the account you're using associated with it, like gmail for instance.

Comment: @yoda That is incorrect. OpenID does not connect the provider's login cookie with the site's login cookie.

Comment: @waiwai933: works for me :)

Comment: ’relax,’ said the Skeet man, 
We are programmed to receive. 
You can checkout any time you like, 
But you can never leave!

Answer (score 13):

**Edit**: This is out of date again; rather than maintain it, just go to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222556/145982) that this is closed as a duplicate of.

---

<s>The answers on this are a bit out of date now. As of 11 March there is a popup when you mouseover your name in the top bar; the logout link appears in that box:</s>

[image: Screenshot of the logout link]

Comment: Yes! I was out of the StackOverflow that was weird feeling :D

Comment: And now this one is out of date!  My name doesn't appear, and my avatar has no pop-up.

Comment: if somebody is still reading, I am not able to see my name or a logout button. How do I logout?