# Is there a log out button on stackoverflow.com

Tags: discussion, logout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I log out of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81773/how-do-i-log-out-of-stack-overflow)

Is there a log out button on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Wrong place to ask, but yes. Click the arrow next to your name at the top and you'll see logout.

Comment: Sorry to revive this thread but, where would you have asked this question (or any questions that are related to how stackoverflow or any stackexchange site works)? Cause i had the same question and was about to post it here. Thanks for your advice. Or was this question originated at stackoverflow and was moved here? Which would answer my question directly.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ is the place