# I can't find the logout button!

Tags: support, top-bar, logout

These answer are no longer valid! [Where is the Sign out link?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176237/where-is-the-sign-out-link) and [Is there a log out button on stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86092/is-there-a-log-out-button-on-stackoverflow-com) and [How do I log out of Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81773/how-do-i-log-out-of-stack-overflow)

**Can someone post a picture of where the logout button is, I've searched everywhere for it! I really can't find it.**

In this post ([Log out button illogical placement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210002/log-out-button-illogical-placement)) they mention that it is in the site switch, but I can't find it there either

Comment: I don't understand... why would you ever want to log out? ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is available under the "Site Switch" menu:

[image]

Comment: -1 your circle isn't freehand.

Comment: -1, circle not free-hand, +1 circle has a drop shadow

Comment: @MichaelT: It's taken me years, but I finally mastered the art of freehand ellipse drawing on a touchpad.

Comment: lol, I don't think I can accept this answer if it doesn't have a freehand circle...

Comment: Shouldn't this be posted as an answer to the other question? (I.e., shouldn't the other question be updated as appropriate?)

Comment: Freehand *PLUS* a drop-shadow... Bam!

Comment: @Werner ***Must... upvote...***

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Good question. Or the other closed as a duplicate of this one since this one is "more correct" under the new top bar. Hmmm.

Comment: @Werner it seems like a case of [How to deal with obsolete answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11705/225437)