# Where is the icon to exit the site?

Tags: support, logout

I just signed up. I'm not computer savvy. Where is the sign-out option? I've pressed on icons but I haven't found one that allows me to sign out.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O4R5.png

Comment: No, I still don't see a way out. I'm just going to turn off the browser page.

Comment: What about my answer dosen't make sense? I'm happy to help but I don't see what you do, or don't

Comment: @richhultin actually, closing the browser page or tab will not log you out. You will still be logged in.

Comment: To Journeyman Geek On Strike, I figured out your graphics today after I stumbled onto the hamburger icon and looked back at what you wrote, thanks

Answer (score 8):

It *is* a little tricky to find.

Click on the 'SE' icon  - this looks a little like a speech bubble crossed with a burger

[image]

The log out button is over there.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this basically a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268527/326191 ?

Comment: Possibly but op apparently couldn't find it, seemed lost and I couldn't quite fit an helpful answer into a comment.